# How do I create an asynchronous loop in the background?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hate asking such a seemingly general question, but everywhere I search they seem to skirt around this issue.

I want to create a program that has a loop that fetches data from a server every 5 seconds and posts. I realized I need to use asynchronousity to do this.

I read several articles related to asynchronousity, but each article referenced a method that was asynchronous, but nothing said directly, "Okay, this is how you create an async loop".

The common threads that I have found so far reference:
-Callbacks (passing an anon function into another function?)
-Call()/apply()
-Jquery methods

It seems one of the way to activate an asynchronous function is through using a call back. Does this mean that every-time I pass a function as a variable, that the function is going to run independently of the rest of my scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use setinterval() function.

```
setInterval(function(){
  $.ajax({ ... });
},5000);
```

Comment: Is this async because an anon function is being passed or because ajax is being used?

Comment: It is async because the function is only called when after 5000 ms.

Comment: I wouldn't do it every 5s, I would do it 5s after the most recent request returns.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like a heavy load for ajax....but

```
setInterval(function(){
   $.ajax({
     url:---,
     type:--,
     data:--,
    success: function (data) {
      myfunction(data); //will call when ajax has finished i.e. callback
    }
   });
 },5000);
```

all ajax is asyc....A..jax!